# jQuery - show multiple divs with multiple triggers

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page are repeating triggers, which should open (change the visibility) a specific form on click. On some pages, there are multiple triggers and forms.

The HTML markup is like this:

```
<div id="form-container-1">
  <a id="form-trigger-1">Open Form</a>
  <div id="form-1">
    content of form
  </div>
</div>
<div id="form-container-2">
  <a id="form-trigger-2">Open Form</a>
  <div id="form-2">
    content of form
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to work on a script, where on click on #form-trigger-x the resonating form (#form-x) get's displayed. That's not the problem, but I want to automate this, so if a page has one form it works and also if it has 10 forms it works, without the need to hardcode every number in the script.

I tried an approach with .each and $(this) but it opened all forms at once instead of the form that should be triggered.

Comment: _but it opened all forms at once instead of the form that should be triggered._ which form should be triggered ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey If you click on #form-trigger-2 the #form-2 should be opened and so on :)

Comment: Give the div you want to show/hide a class. In the trigger click code, point to a div of that class under the parent of the trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to add click event on all the `a` tag where `id` starts with `form-trigger` with

```
$("a[id^='form-trigger']").click(function(){
```

And then you just need to get the [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) of clicked `a` tag and play with its display property or whatever you want like

```
$(this).next()
```

```js
$("a[id^='form-trigger']").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
})

$(".btn").click(function(){
   $(this).closest("div").slideToggle();
})
```

```css
#form-2{
  display:none;
}
#form-1{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form-container-1">
  <a id="form-trigger-1">Open Form</a>
  <div id="form-1">
    content of form 1
   <button type="button" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close form 1</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="form-container-2">
  <a id="form-trigger-2">Open Form</a>
  <div id="form-2">
    content of form 2
       <button type="button" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close form 2</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a very elegant solution :) Inside the #form-x div I have another link that closes the form. How can I implement that into the script?

Comment: you'll have to show me where does it exist in the from so I can advise better

Comment: Sure it's like this: <div id="form-2">some content <button id=trigger-close" type="button"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close form</button></div>

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I approached this. You don't need to target them with specific ID value, Instead, use classes because the basic structure of each container is same it would work no matter how many different forms you got.

When you click on the anchor tag, my script would look for closest form-container class and find the showform class in that dom element and show it.

I have added the code snippet below as an example.

Hope this helps!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="form-container-1" class="form-container">
  <a  onclick="showform(this);" id="form-trigger-1">Open Form</a>
  <div id="form-1" class="showform hide">
    content of form
  </div>
</div>
<div id="form-container-2" class="form-container">
  <a  onclick="showform(this);" id="form-trigger-3">Open Form</a>
  <div id="form-2" class="showform hide">
    content of form
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function showform(caller){
$(caller).closest(".form-container").find(".showform").removeClass('hide');
}
</script>
```